# How to use extern NSString for move the string value from first view to second View Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I would like to use `extern NSString` for moving the string value from **First View controller** to **Second View Controller**.

is there any example that show how to use `extern NSString` to pass data between two view controllers.

Thank you.

Comment: Possibly, but is a bad idea. You should set a property on your second view controller, either in `prepareForSegue` or directly if you aren't using segues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

in your first view controller :

```
extern NSString *Str;
```

Then define it in `@interface`

```
@interface{
NSString *Str;
}
```

Then assign the value as per your requirement in `@Implementation`

and then you can use `Str` as a variable in second view controller

Comment: Thanks, But when i try to use Str in second view controller i get error : linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: If you use Xcode 7 or later just do this---->  Menu > Product > Clean, this is what made it work.and then Run your project.I hope it works for you.:)